# Mi conexion de #MYSQL se pierde

Tags: java, mysql

Mi error es el siguiente, al momento de correr mi sistema Java si se ejecuta, inserta, elimina etc. Pero si lo dejo abierto por 5 o 10 min aprox, e intento volver a utilizarlo para guardar un registro me manda el siguiente error:

> non transient connection exception mysql

Dejo el codigo que utilizo para la conexion:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class conectar {

    Connection conect = null;

    public Connection conexion() {
        try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           conect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/redesco1_10deenero","root","");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error "+e);
        }
        return conect;      
    }
}
```

Comment: Eso te debe pasar porque tu motor de BD debe tener un tiempo de sesión y cuando pasa ese tiempo se cierra la conexión automáticamente. Deberías mirar la configuración de la base de datos y consultar eso.

Comment: No es normal lo que te ocurre, el tiempo de espera por defecto suele ser de 8 horas (28800 segundos), como muestra el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout). ¿No habrás estando trasteando en la configuración o establecido en alguna parte un tiempo de espera menor? ¿Tienes todo al día y en regla: JDBC, versión de MySQL, Java, etc.?

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2569962/5215609

Comment: @A.Cedano no configure nada, ya que estoy trabajando la BD en un Host. Nunca habia tenido este error hasta que conecte el programa a una BD alojada en internet. Y no se donde indicar el tiempo de espera de conexión :(

Answer (score 0):

Yo trabajo la Shell de MySQL y me ocurría algo similar, por lo que ahora entro con una conexión momentánea.

```
\connect root@localhost (enter)
```

Y ya pones tu contraseña.